# deduction guides for std::array

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I go through the book C++ template unique quide and I try to understand how the deduction guides for `std::array` works.
Regarding the definition of the standard the following is the declaration

```
template <class T, class... U>
array(T, U...) -> array<T, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;
```

For example if in main a array created as

```
std::array a{42,45,77}
```

How the deduction takes place?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How the deduction takes place?

It's simple.

Calling

```
std::array a{42,45,77}
```

match

```
array(T, U...)
```

with `T = decltype(42)` and `U... = decltype(45), decltype(77)` that is `T = int` and `U... = int, int`.

So the type of `a{42,45,47}` become `array<T, 1 + sizeof...(U)>`, so `std::array<int, 1 + sizeof...(int, int)>`, so `std::array<int, 1 + 2>` that is `std::array<int, 3>`

In other words: are extracted the types of the arguments; the first one (`T`) is used to give the type the array (first template parameter); the others are used just to be counted (`sizeof...(U)`). But, for the template second parameter, it's important to count also the first argument (of type `T`, so the `1` in `1 + sizeof...(U)`).